# Can not quite undestand pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am quite new to C and still got problems understanding pointers.

```
int main() {
    char input[20];
    char* ptr;
    node* head = NULL;
    head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

    do {
        printf("Eingabe: ");
        fgets(input,20,stdin);

        if (*input == '0') { 
            break;
        }

        ptr = strtok(input," ");

        while(ptr!=NULL){
            int val = atoi(ptr);
            push(head,val);
            ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }   

        bubbleSort(head);
        printf("Ausgabe: ");
        printList(head);
        printf("\n");

    } while(*input != '0');

    free(head);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, `strtok(input," ");` does the function `strtok` return the address of the first token, or the value of this token?

I was thinking that if you want the value, you have to dereference it with an asterisk.

I tried to print the `ptr` with the star and this gives me the address of this token and not the value. This even confused me more. Can someone expalin this to me?

Comment: It return the address of the first token. There is no such thing as a "string" typer in C. Basically in C a "string" is a pointer to the first character of the string.

Comment: if it returns the adress, when I try to print it without asterisk like printf("%d",ptr), why does this not give me the address?

Comment: It kind of does, but you can't use %d for printing the value of a pointer, you need to use %p. But that's just a memory address which is not really useful to you.

Comment: You can use `%s` to print the value of a string.

Comment: @Jabberwocky So when I print it with a star for my undestanding it should display the value to which it is pointing right?

Comment: @yassoplaya yes, more or less. `printf("%c", *ptr)` will print the first character of the string pointed by `ptr`. I think you need to read the chapter dealing with pointers in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: I understood it now , thanks for explaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say your input looks like this:

```
--------------------
|2|3| |5| |1|2|3|\0|
--------------------
```

The final `\0` is the string terminator. Everything after that is ignored.

When you first call `ptr = strtok(input, " ")`, `strtok` will return the location of the first character that is not a space. It will also replace the first space with `\0`, and use an internally saved pointer to remember how far it got.
The  situation will look like this:

```
---------------------
|2|3|\0|5| |1|2|3|\0|
---------------------
 ^      ^
 ptr    internal pointer
```

So `ptr` is a pointer to a position inside the array (`ptr`'s type is `char*`).

You then call `atoi(ptr)` to transform the string `23\0` into an integer, `23`. This works because `strtok` replaced the space with a `\0`.

You then call `ptr = strtok(NULL, " ")`. Passing `NULL` as the first parameter tells `strtok` to use its internally saved pointer as the starting point while looking for the next token. The result is this:

```
-------------------------
|2|3|\0|5|\0|1|2|3|\0|
-------------------------
        ^    ^
        ptr  internal pointer
```

So what `atoi` sees is `5\0`, i.e. the string `"5"`, which it translates into the integer `5`. Then you again call `strtok(NULL, " ")`, and you get the result `123` from `atoi`. Then the following `strtok` returns `NULL`, since it finds no more tokens, and you start again with the next line of input.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
ptr = strtok(input," ");
```

the function `strtok` returns a pointer to the first element of the entered string that is not equal to the balnk character. That is the function returns pointer to the first character of substring that is delimited by blank characters.

Pay attention to that it is better to write at least like

```
ptr = strtok(input,"\n ");
```

because the function fgtes can append the new line character to the entered string.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "123 456 789";

    char *p = strtok( s, " " );

    while ( p != NULL )
    {
        int x = atoi( p );
        printf( "%d\n", x );
        p = strtok( NULL, " " );
    }        
}
```

Its output is

```
123
456
789
```

After the first call of strtok the function changed the source string replacing the blank character with the terminaring zero character the following way

```
"123 456 789" ===> "123\000456 789"
                       ^^^^
```

and returned a pointer to the extracted substring `"123"`

in the second call the function deals with the string `"456 789"`.

Again it builds a substring by inserting the terminating zero character

```
"456 789" ===> "456\000789"
```

and returns a pointer to the substring "456". And so on.